# How to force using new jsp session attributes after jQuery AJAX loading?

Tags: jsp, jquery, session

For the question I am trying to show only the relevant code (please, see below).
As a result of calling to *user.jsp* in the function *loadUser* the session attributes change.  These session attributes are used in the jQuery function *loadActions* that loads *actions.jsp*

However, **only if Internet Explorer is set to check for newer versions of stored pages every visit to the webpage** then the change in session attributes is visible in *actions.jsp*.  Otherwise,   these session attributes do not change at all after calling *loadUser* several times.

Mozilla seems to be working properly.

Is there any possibility to force using new session attributes in the function loadActions?

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    loadUser();
});

var loadUser = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'user.jsp',
    data: {…},
    success: function (data) {…},
    error: function (data) {…},
    complete: function () {
        loadActions();
    }
});
}

var loadActions = function () {
     $('#actionsList').load('actions.jsp #print, #letters');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a unique parameter to the call so IE doesn't think the page can be cached:

```
$('#actionsList').load('actions.jsp?' + (new Date()).getTime() + ' #print, #letters');
```

Comment: This helps! But only for 2-3 times. Further clicking resulted in the same problem. Any thought?

Comment: I needed to do a similar trick in some other places to prevent cache